# Is it possible to build network map cluster on Corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

Is it possible to build a network map cluster to allow high availability and to prevent single point of failure from using a single node?

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of this concern. In the near future, Corda will move towards an architecture where instead of a single node serving as the network map, the network map will be a set of digitally-signed files distributed using a CDN-style service.

This will make the network map highly available.